# ListView & Custom Adapter dont work Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I don’t understand why the list is not filled with the help of a custom adapter. Only the last element from the array gets into textView (textHeroView). And it turns out that the ListView does not go as a list, but simply with one item from the array. I tried to put it on a separate list, to no avail. Can you please tell me what I made a mistake?

***HeroesAdapter***

```
class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<TestHero>): BaseAdapter() {
    private val context = context
    private val heroes = heroes

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heroes.count()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return heroes[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

           // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
        val listheroView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_hero_view, parent, false)
           // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
            val heroText: TextView = listheroView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
            val category = heroes[position]

           // heroText.text = category.legends.all.keys.first()
        for((key) in category.legends.all){
            Log.d("HeroesActivity", key)
            heroText.text = key
        }

            return listheroView

    }
}
```

***list_hero_view***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heroesImageView"
        android:layout_width="426dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wraith_apex_legends" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeroView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wraith"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***activity_heroes***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HeroesActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/heroesListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNickname"
        android:layout_width="251dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="279dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Nickname"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.145"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.272" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLvl"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:text="Lvl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.562" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***HeroesActivity***

```
class HeroesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var heroesAdapt : HeroesAdapter

    val listHero = ArrayList<TestHero>()
    private val TAG = "HeroesActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_heroes)

        getCurrentData()

        val lisView : ListView = findViewById(R.id.heroesListView)

        heroesAdapt = HeroesAdapter(this, listHero)
        lisView.adapter = heroesAdapt
        //heroesListView.adapter = heroesAdapt
        
            // heroesAdapt = HeroesAdapter(this, arrayListOf("a","b","c","d","e","f"));
        // lisView.adapter = heroesAdapt


    }

    private fun getCurrentData() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.herList().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString())

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                   // adapter.add(data.global.name)
                   // adapt.add(data.global.platform)

                    listHero.add(data)
                    heroesAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    textNickname.text = "${data.global.name} (${data.global.rank.rankDiv} divisions)"
                    textLvl.text = "Level: ${data.global.level.toString()}"
                    when(data.global.rank.rankName){
                        "Silver" -> textNickname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A7A79"))
                        "Gold" ->   textNickname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E6D600"))
                        "Platinum" -> textNickname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#36BBCE"))
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in this piece of code

```
    for((key) in category.legends.all){
        Log.d("HeroesActivity", key)
        heroText.text = key
    }
```

[image]

And logs screen

[image: logs logs screen]

***TestHero.kt***

```
data class TestHero (@SerializedName("global") val global: PlayerInf,
                     @SerializedName("legends")val legends: AllLegends)

data class  PlayerInf (val name: String, val uid: Long, val avatar: String, val platform: String,
val  level: Int, val toNextLevelPercent: Int, val internalUpdateCount: Int, val bans: BanInf, val rank: RankInf)

data class BanInf (val isActive: Boolean, val remainingSeconds: Int)

data class RankInf (val rankScore: Int, val rankName: String, val rankDiv: Int, val rankImg: String)


data class AllLegends (@SerializedName("all") val all: Map<String, LegendWrapper> = emptyMap())


data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()

)
data class PlayerPerformance(val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String)
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 i can just do ```return position.toLong()``` ? because if i don't define this parameter i get the error

Comment: @Tenfour04 I  hope this does not affect the performance of my adapter?

Comment: Regarding your newly shared code: you're only putting one piece of data in your list, so of course it only has one line item. Also, don't use a constant mutable list in your adapter, because when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, then it cannot compare between the old and new lists. Also, if you modify the list without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it has the potential to crash or show duplicate items or skip items because it doesn't know the list size has changed. And never use GlobalScope (you can google why not). You should do this in a ViewModel and use `viewModelScope`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you very much, I will definitely read and apply all your recommendations, at the study stage, any advice from specialists like you helps me

Comment: @Tenfour04    ```for((key) in heroes.legends.all){
   Log.d("HeroesActivity", key)
   holder.heroesName?.text = key
 }```
can this piece of code not fill the list correctly? in C # this would clearly be a problem

Comment: @Tenfour04 excuse me for bothering you, I'm just trying for the whole day to find at least a little clue on the way to solving my problem

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you have the opportunity to post as a response, do so and I'll close the topic. And I will go look for the answers to what you pointed to me on Google. Anyway you helped me a lot

Comment: I take back what I said about NO_ID. I didn't realize you're using ArrayAdapter and ListView instead of Adapter and RecyclerView. Just return the position.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ok. Thank you for help me <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the adapter, it's one item for one view. Your backing List has only one item.  Your for loop inside `getView()` is iterating some collection inside that single item, and setting the value of the same TextView over and over until it gets to the last one.

Since the backing type of your adapter is TestHero, your list view can only show one line item per instance of TestHero. You only have one instance of TestHero.

Based on what you're showing, you should make the backing type of your adapter whatever the type of the list `TestHero.legends.all` is. In your coroutine, you can pull that list out of your TestHero and pass it to your Adapter. You'll need to make the backing list property mutable.

And like I said in the comments, don't use mutable lists for this. You should start with an empty list.

For example, if the type of this list is Legend, your adapter should look something like:

```
class HeroesAdapter(): BaseAdapter() {
    var heroes: List<Legend> = emptyList()

    override fun getCount(): Int = heroes.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): = heroes[position]

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_hero_view, parent, false)
        val heroText: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
        val hero = heroes[position]
        heroText.text = hero.keys.first()
        return view
    }
}
```

And in your Activity, get rid of the `listHero` property. In your coroutine, after you get your data, do

```
heroesAdapt.apply {
    heroes = data.legends.all
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Also, consider switching to RecyclerView. ListView is kind of obsolete and I keep expecting them to deprecate it because they have only worked on improving RecyclerView the past several years.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a problem on the topic, namely, due to the fact that I use a map, I cannot explicitly execute this part of the code, because I get a type mismatch error ```heroes = data.legends.all```

Comment: I can’t solve it without knowing the exact types. Use `toList()` and/or `map()` to convert it to what you need.

Comment: I apologize for disturbing you. I figured it out and solved my problem. Thanks again and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue in your code,

try this :

Setting adapter :

```
    binding.heroesListView.adapter = HeroesAdapter(applicationContext, arrayListOf("a","b","c","d","e","f"));
```

Adapter :

```
package com.example.stackoverflow

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.TextView
class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<String>): BaseAdapter() {
    private val context = context
    private val heroes = heroes

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heroes.count()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return heroes[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
        val listheroView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_hero, parent, false)
        // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
        val heroText: TextView = listheroView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
        val category = heroes[position]

        heroText.text = category

        return listheroView

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This example works as expected. Could this be due to coroutines? I will now complement the question

Answer (score 0):

in your list_hero_view.xml, change the height from match parent to wrap content. Thanks me later :-P

[image]

Comment: excuse me, but it seems that wrap_content was originally spelled out there. Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I saw only one place where it was necessary to change, but the result remained the same (

Comment: for your convince i've attached screenshoot from your code.

Comment: yes, that's right, i replaced wrap_content came out with the same result (

Comment: maybe I need to add something else from the code?

Comment: maybe need to write wrap_content in ListView ??

Comment: why list view? can you use recyclerView instead?

Comment: @NehaK I'm just learning android development. Therefore, in the lesson, the first is ListView